# If Then SQL query to count & subtract in a report

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a report (in MRI) using basic SQL functions that will produce a report breaking down a payment by charge code.

I'll be receiving a spreadsheet that includes only a full transaction amount.  However, I have to specify upon import which charge code the payment should be applied to.  So, I've created a table which I import the spreadsheet into, so that I can create the desired report.

Though, I'm a bit stuck.  Currently, I have the report designed to produce:

- COUNT - count per chgcode per nameid
- NAMEID  - client ID
- TRANAMT - payment total
- DISTINCTCHGCODE  - chgcode for balance due per nameid (order by ACF, ALT, ANS, ARC, etc)
- SUMOPENAMT - sum of openamt per chgcode per nameid
- TOTBAL - total balance due per nameid

I need to add a calculation field that will produce:

```
IF TRANAMT>TOTBAL THEN 'manual' 
Else
IF TRANAMT<= SUMOPENAMT and COUNT='1' THEN TRANAMT
Else
IF TRANAMT>SUMOPENAMT AND COUNT='1' and exists SUMOPENAMT where count='2' then SUMOPENAMT 
Else
IF TRANAMT<= SUMOPENAMT and COUNT='2'  less SUMOPENAMT where COUNT='1' then TRANAMT less SUMOPENAMT WHERE COUNT='1'
 Else
IF TRANAMT> SUMOPENAMT and COUNT='2' less SUMOPENAMT where COUNT='1', then SUMOPENAMT
```

and so on and so forth...

Comment: I dont see a question here.

Comment: I am trying to get assistance with the necessary verbiage for the function.

Comment: I don't think that is SQL. If MRI uses some other calculations syntax like SSRS or Crystal Reports then you need to review the documentation for that syntax. SQL would be something like "Case when TRANAMT>TOTBAL then 'manual' when TRANANMT<= SUMPENAMPT... else 'something' end as columnname". Something you might consider is that in some reporting tools, you can refer to named fields directly, e.g. the COUNT might be stored in FIELD1 (like Excel names cells).

Comment: Yes, 'COUNT' is a field.  I'm needing the calculation to be executed based on the value of the TRANAMT field and the SUMOPENAMT field as identified by the associated COUNT field value, or, as the case may be, the difference between 2 or more SUMOPENAMT records as defined by their associated COUNT value.  The platform used is SQL, so the commands in my example may not be useful.  As, I'm not sure of the verbiage, I used those commands simply to illustrate the desired result.